# Using awk to print the number of files given in the command line

Tags: awk

I'm new at Command Lines! I want to use awk in order to print the number of files given in the command line. When I'm trying to do this I go in an endless loop.

```
awk 'BEGIN{};'
awk 'END{print ARGC}'
```

It sarts reading the files but I don't know how to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct syntax is

```
awk 'END {print ARGC}' file1 ... filen
```

be aware that

- file must be given (elase awk will wait for input in stdin
- awk itself count as one in ARGC

to get number of file

```
awk 'END {print ARGC-1}' file1 ... filen
```

---

endless loop

(this should be a comemnt, as nothing give a clues as to why).

suppose you write

```
 foobar="/my/path1 /other/path2"
 C=$(awk 'END{ print ARGC-1}' $fobar)
```

you are likely to go in endless loop/witing for stdin as you mispell `$foobar` as `$fobar`.

Comment: Thank you! And if I want to make a shell script with it how should I write? It also goes in an endless loop. :(